# responsive 3 div side by side with image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to align image and content inside div under div. tried with float left but not working

[Js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aniket9900/9HGdg/4/) for quick overview
here is the CSS:

```
.container {
   clear: both;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
.profile1 {
  background-color: #CCF;
 }
.profile2 {
 background-color: #CFC;
}
.profile3 {
 background-color: #FCC;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 .span_1_of_3 {
  width: 32.2%;
}
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="border:2px solid black;">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 profile1"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 profile2"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3 profile3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain your desired behavior more clearly?

Comment: A picture of what you would like is also very helpful.

Comment: right now image and content not align side by side.Content start at the bottom of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating image to the left seems to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rTZJ9/.

```
.col > img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DRD's aswer is good and You may also use  `align="left"` inside `img` tag.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" align="left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sharanpreet ***The align attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.***

Comment: This should be listed as a comment instead of an answer.